# Resolving collision with nuget libraries when referencing netstandard dll from netframework project

Tags: .net, wpf, json.net, .net-standard

I've got a netstandard class library project that is shared between a Core app and a WPF app. This class library uses Newtonsoft.Json via Nuget and from what I understand links in the .NETStandard 1.3 version of it.

The WPF app also uses Newtonsoft.Json and links in the .NETFramework version. This compiles but gives me a collision when attempting to use the Json library, resulting in a System.TypeLoadException on the first use(attempting to Serialize an object if that makes any difference). More specifically it fails to load the type Newtonsoft.Json.SerializationBinder.

I've been trying to resolve this for a couple of hours without really getting anywhere, if anyone has any pointers they'd be much appreciated.